# Listening to onchange function of web component(made with react) within angular component

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs, web-component

I am using a datepicker web component made of react within angular application. I want to access the value once the user select the date from the date picker.

1) first scenario,I saw few posts and tried the below format but the setSelectedDates function is not at all called when the datepicker is selected.

**Within component template file(html)**

```
<dnb-date-picker
          [show_input]="true"
          [start_date]="2019-04-01"
          [end_date]="2019-04-01"
          [range]="true"
          [link]="true"
          [return_format]="dd-MM-yyyy"
          [mask_placeholder]="dd-MM-yyyy"
          (on_change)="setSelectedDates($event)"
      ></dnb-date-picker>
```

**Within component.ts**

```
setSelectedDates(startDate: any, endDate: any): void {
    console.log(startDate);
    console.log(endDate);
  }
```

2) second scenario, tried the below format and setSelectedDates function is getting triggered but value is coming as undefined.

**Within component template file(html)**

```
<dnb-date-picker
          show_input="true"
          start_date="2019-04-01"
          end_date="2019-04-01"
          range="true"
          link="true"
          return_format="dd-MM-yyyy"
          mask_placeholder="dd-MM-yyyy"
          [_change]="setSelectedDates(start_date,end_date)"
      ></dnb-date-picker>
```

**Within component.ts**

```
 setSelectedDates(startDate: any, endDate: any): void {
    console.log(startDate);
    console.log(endDate);
  }
```

kindly provide some inputs.

Comment: Please provide API of the datepicker. There is no way to answer without it. Also `setSelectedDates(startDate: any, endDate: any):` even if called, endDate allways be undefined, as template callback will pass only one param - value of `$event`

Comment: https://eufemia.dnb.no/uilib/components/date-picker/properties

Comment: please check this to see how this web component works. https://codesandbox.io/s/eufemia-html-umd-usage-bk40z